# GPS tracking in Kinetise application

Tags: mobile, web, gps, code-generation

Anyone here familiar with Kinetise? I try to add to my app some kind of remote tracking functionality, where backend will trigger from active user his GPS position. What first come to my mind was PUSH notifications, but it's rather message notification than event triggering in this tool. In taxi template there is a map with live changing positions, realized by longpooling requests I think. I found that you can add your current position in request params or body and I consider to use this technique to send user location to server, but I think that I would have to add empty lists in each screen, just to send a location. A bit weird but maybe there is any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

[@Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6952941/marek-d%C4%85browik) for GPS purposes you have also functions:

- GPS TRACKING START
- GPS TRACKING STOP

You can add it to buttons from widget "EVENTS" tab.

[EVENTS tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLVt.png)

I know it's not triggered by server but can help you meet your requirements.